# How to represent float values in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to create a database in Ubuntu using MySQL in the command line, I need to create a table with the following data:

```
CREATE TABLE Vehicles (
     Vehicle_ID int NOT NULL,
     Vehicle_Type VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
     Model_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
     Engine_Size float(1,1) NOT NULL,
     Condition VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
     Price float(9,2) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (Vehicle_ID)
);
```

It just returns an error that says "ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Condition varchar(255) NOT NULL,
Price float(9,2) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (Vehicle' at line 6"

What is wrong with my code? The "Price" and "Engine_Size" columns need to only be a float/decimal values so they can't be varchar because I want to only be able to insert numbers.

Comment: `CONDITION` is a [*reseved word*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html).

Comment: `Condition` is a [MySQL reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-C) and must be enclosed in backticks to use as a column name.

Comment: @HarryStanford unrelated, but you really need to change these to `DECIMAL` columns.  `FLOAT` and `DOUBLE` should be used very rarely and only by deliberate choice.

Answer (score 3):

This works:

```
CREATE TABLE Vehicles (
     Vehicle_ID int NOT NULL,
     Vehicle_Type VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
     Model_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
     Engine_Size int NOT NULL,
     Vehicle_Condition VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
     Price numeric(9,2) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (Vehicle_ID)
);
```

Notes:

- For `Price` you seem to want `numeric`, not `float`, because you are specifying the precision and scale.
- For `Engine_Size`, I have no idea what `float(1, 1)` is supposed to mean.  I am guessing that `int` is an appropriate type.
- `Condition` is a reserved word in MySQL, so I changed the name of the column.

Comment: I guess `Engine_Size` is meant to be `numeric(2,1)`.

Comment: How is this not a duplicate of the question I closed with? [`FLOAT(M,D)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/floating-point-types.html) is perfectly valid MySQL, the *only* error in the table definition was the use of the reserved word `Condition` which could be fixed by surrounding it with backticks, as described in the duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

The only apparent problem in your code is the use of 'condition' as a column name as `condition` is a reserved word in MySQL.
You can fix it in 2 ways:

- Don't use 'condition' as a column name:

```
CREATE TABLE Vehicles (
     Vehicle_ID int NOT NULL,
     Vehicle_Type VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
     Model_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
     Engine_Size float(1,1) NOT NULL,
     V_Condition VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,       //Just an example feel free to use any another name
     Price float(9,2) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (Vehicle_ID)
);
```

- Put 'condition' inside backticks (``)

```
CREATE TABLE Vehicles (
     Vehicle_ID int NOT NULL,
     Vehicle_Type VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
     Model_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
     Engine_Size float(1,1) NOT NULL,
     `Condition` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
     Price float(9,2) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (Vehicle_ID)
);
```

Hope this helps